# Blowing up fibers in families - looking for comparison results

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Given a morphism $\pi: S\rightarrow B $, an ideal sheaf $I$ on $S$, and a point $b\in B$, I wish to consider the blow up of $S$ along $I$.

Say I know something about the pullback $I(b)$ to the fiber $S(b)$ over $b$ and I have a pretty good idea what the resulting blowup of $S(b)$ along $I(b)$ looks like -- then i'd like to use this information to say something about the fibers $Bl(S,I)\rightarrow B$. The resulting fiber wills of this map will of course be different than the fiber and the blow up that I understand, but it seems like I should be able to say something anyway and I can in special cases. Has anyone dealt with this comparison at the level of generality as stated? Or can refer me to a paper which deals with it implicitly?

Also, feel free to assume that the subvariety determined by $I$ is smooth.
Edit: I can also assume that the subscheme determined by $I$ is transverse to fibers.